# Using Determinant to Show Linear Dependence

Tags: linear-algebra

Hi all I am just working through a few problems and one question asks under what conditions is the given set of vectors linearly dependent. These are just three dimensional vectors with two of them containing parameters instead of a specified value.

I have written these vectors as column vectors and put them into a matrix and found the determinant which was: t + 4s - 2 where t and s are the two parameters.

I know that when the determinant of a matrix composed of column vectors is zero they are linearly dependent but I am struggling to understand why this is the case or why that another way to show this set is linearly dependent if the row reduced echelon form contained a row containing only zeros.

Thank you.

Comment: You just need to conclude that the given vectors are linearly dependent when the parameters $s$ and $t$ satisfy the equation $t+4s-2=0$

Comment: Ah thank you I would have forgotten that point. But why is it the case that when this happens they are linearly dependent?

Comment: You said it yourself. When the determinant is zero the columns are linearly dependent. In this case the determinant is zero whenever $s$ and $t$ satisfy the mentioned equation.